# What's the difference in both of these memory locations?

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

```
stringstream ss("1,2,3");
char ch;
int a,b,c;
ss >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c;

cout << &ss << endl << ss;
```

I'm getting 2 Values which are similar but not same, What's the difference between them?
I'm still in the phase of learning so it'll be really helpful if someone could throw light about both of their meanings as well (if I'm wrong about the fact that they are memory locations)

Outputs :

```
0x73fc50
0x73fcd0
```

Comment: [Your code doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/37636rWrh). `cout << ... << ss` isn't valid.

Comment: But it is compiling on VS Code :(

Comment: What compiler are you using (VS Code is an editor), MSVC? What are you trying to do when attempting to print `ss`? Did you mean `cout << ... << ss.str()` instead?

Comment: Where can i see my compiler? I use some extension called Code Runner to run my code in Vs Code :/

Comment: The `ss` variable is a **stream** that pulls data from a string.  The expression `&ss` returns the location of the stream variable.  The `cout << ss` is undefined because there isn't an overload of `operator<<` defined for a `stringstream`.

Comment: I think it is TDM GCC compiler

Comment: I don't use VS Code so I don't know. Does VS Code output anything when you compile the code? If you're on Windows you're probably using MSVC, unless you're running through something like cygwin or minGW

Comment: Yeah it outputs G++ followed by the name of my file.cpp and yeah i think I installed something called Mingw while setting up VS Code

Comment: Oh so it's the Undefined behavior again, I think I encountered another one of these in my previous question. But Thanks, Now I know what it is :)